# Finding All permutations of a list when given a function that returns the next permutation of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

In my assignment this week I was asked to write a python script that takes a number n and returns all permutations of [0,1,2,...,n-1]. So far I have written a script that takes a list and returns the next permutation of the list. I am looking for ideas on how I can write the script based on what I've written so far.

```
def next_permutation(p):
    a = len(p)
    i = a -2 
    while i >= 0 and p[i] >= p[i+1]:
        i = i-1
    if i == -1:
        return []

    j = i+1
    while j < a and p[j] >= p[i]:
        j += 1
    j-=1

    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]

    k = i + 1
    l = a - 1

    while k < l:
        p[k], p[l] = p[l], p[k]
        k += 1
        l -= 1
    return p
```

EDIT: this is the code that returns the next permutation of a list. I wrote this entirely based on the instruction provided by my instructor.

Comment: "So far I have written a script that takes a list and returns the next permutation of the list." Where is that? Please post it.

Comment: Yes I have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to have all the permutations of a list with numbers from 0 to n-1, you already have clear steps that you need to take:

1. Create a list that contains all numbers from 0 to n-1:

This can be easily done with the in-built `range()` function since it is mostly used for exactly that purpose:

> [***range(stop)***](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#range)
>
> This is a versatile function to create iterables yielding arithmetic progressions.

2. Calculate the amount of permutations that such list would have:

Math tells us that having N elements, there will be N! different permutations of those elements, wher **!** means factorial. We can import factorial function from math module which would quickly allow us to calculate the amount of permutations your list will have:

```
from math import factorial
print(factorial(4)) # 24
```

3. Call your function `next_permutation(p)` that you already wrote that many times and yield each and every permutation.

To *return* something more than once from a function, you can use *yield* insted.

With these steps in mind, you can create something similar to this:

```
def all_permutations(n):

    # Constructing a list that contains all numbers from 0 to n-1
    integer_list = list(range(n))

    # Calculating the amount of permutations such list would have
    permutation_count = factorial(n)

    # Output that many permutations
    for _ in range(permutation_count):
        yield integer_list
        integer_list = next_permutation(integer_list)
```

This generator function will yield all permutations of a list containing numbers from 0 to n-1 which is exactly what you need.

To create a list that would contain all of the permutations you can write something simple like:

```
n = 4
all_permutations = list(all_permutations(n))
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I understand the use of yield in this case, but is there a way that I can put all the results in a list?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.